# Extraer el numero de una lista(secuencia)

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

no se si el titulo esta bien especificado soy nuevo en esto, el punto es: a mi me dan ciertas listas. Ejemplo:

```
list1=[0, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2=[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
list3=[2, 3, 4, 5]
list4=[4, 8, 9, 10]
```

Necesito extraer el primer numero de la secuencia, es decir, en list1 la lista es 0,2,3,4,5. No obstante la secuencia es 2,3,4,5 porque son seguidos, en ese caso se imprimiría el numero 2 lo mismo con list2 y list3, ya que tienen la misma secuencia. Con list4 se imprimiría el numero 8. Y la verdad no se cual seria el proceso lógico a seguir. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto es un poco matar pulgas a cañonazos, pero no me resisto a poner una solución que usa numpy para resolver el problema en una línea:

```
import numpy as np

def primer_secuencia(lista):
  return lista[list(np.diff(lista)).index(1)]
```

¿Cómo funciona? Usando `np.diff(lista)` se obtiene otra lista que contiene la diferencia entre cada número con el siguiente. Por ejemplo, si la lista es `0, 2, 3, 4, 5]` el resultado sería `[2, 1, 1, 1]`. Seguidamente el método `.index()` busca un dato en esa lista resultante. En este caso buscamos el 1, y se nos retornará el índice del primer 1 que se encuentre. Usamos ese índice para seleccionar en `lista[]` el valor correspondiente, que es lo que retornamos.

Demo de funcionamiento:

```
list1=[0, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2=[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
list3=[2, 3, 4, 5]
list4=[4, 8, 9, 10]
for l in (list1, list2, list3, list4):
  print(primer_secuencia(l))
```

Imprime:

```
2
2
2
8
```

Answer (score 0):

para ello vendría bien que creases una función que tomase la lista como parámetro.

Dentro de la función, recorrer la lista y comprobar que el número + 1 es igual que el siguiente número de la lista. Si coinciden es que hay secuencia, por tanto, ya sabemos dónde empieza y así devolvemos ese número.

```py
def primer_secuencia(lista):
    for key, num in enumerate(lista):
        try:
            if(num + 1 == lista[key+1]):
                return num
        except IndexError:
            return 'No hay secuencia'
```

Ejemplo:

```py
list1=[0, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2=[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
list3=[2, 3, 4, 5]
list4=[4, 8, 9, 10]
list5=[4, 8, 10, 12]

def primer_secuencia(lista):
    for key, num in enumerate(lista):
        try:
            if(num + 1 == lista[key+1]):
                return num
        except IndexError:
            return 'No hay secuencia'
    
print(primer_secuencia(list1)) # 2
print(primer_secuencia(list2)) # 2
print(primer_secuencia(list3)) # 2
print(primer_secuencia(list4)) # 8
print(primer_secuencia(list5)) # 'No hay secuencia'
```